# Send multiple image from a server to an React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a server which handle a folder with multiple images.
I want to receive 30 images based on the page number in my react app

page 1 : img 0->29

page 2 : img 30->59

page 3 : img 60->89

I know how to do that with a single image with

```
res.send(file) on the server side
fetch(url).then(blob) on the react side
```

but how do i do with 30 ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array or JSON-Object with the Meta-Data of your images (e.g [ 0 => {filename, path, thumbnailPath, size, }].

In your App, this Object is used if you try to load something. E.g if you wan't to download images 0 - 10, loop over your Array, and for each entry, fetch the files like done before.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. You can get all the images from the server and store it in the array inside component's state.On page 1 show only 30 images and on page 2 show other 30 images..., this way you can show images depending page number.
2. Other way is that your API should support pagination.Once you pass page number to API, It should return images accordingly.
3. You can use any open source module that support pagination, you just need to pass array to that module. Check this one [react pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate)